# Eureka server does not register service application

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm starting both applications but eureka server isn't registering service application. I'm using Spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE version. Ther is my dependencies in service application:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

And application.yml file:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  application:
    name: test1

server:
  port: 2222
```

Eureka server application dependencies:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

All names and urls are correct and I have no idea why it isn't working. Could anyone help me with my problem ?

Comment: Are you using a Docker container? Is the Eureka Server Running on a container or a remote host?

Comment: I'm not using docker. I'm starting all applications locally on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the previous dependency name you have used was only supported till 1.4.6 (Edgware release train). In the future, the easiest way to generate Spring Boot app poms in order to ensure the dependency versions are in keeping, is to do it at https://start.spring.io/ .

Answer (score 0):

The problem has gone when i have changed previous dependencies for this one:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```